# On setAdapter it does not invoke getView method of Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

The problem is getView method does not get called even when I do setAdapter on listView. Please see may code below. I dont get any error message. It just does not display reviewer data. Would you please suggest what I am doing incorrect.

MovieReviewerFragmemt class I have below code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (ArrayList movieDetailsArray){
        getMovieArrayList(movieDetailsArray);
        ListView listView = (ListView)                                    rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_detail_reviewerlist);
        MovieAddlDetail detail = (MovieAddlDetail) movieDetailsArray.get(0);
        MovieReviewers[] list = detail.getReviewerArrayList();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "MovieReviewerFragment - CustomReviewerAdapter - calling adapter");
        movieDetailAdapter = new CustomReviewerAdapter(getActivity(), list);
        movieDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(movieDetailAdapter);
    }
```

CustomerReviewAdapter:

```
public class CustomReviewerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private final String LOG_TAG1 = CustomReviewerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private MovieReviewers[] reviewers;

public CustomReviewerAdapter(Context context, MovieReviewers[] reviewers) {
    super(context, R.layout.fragment_detail, reviewers);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "CustomReviewerAdapter - constructor");
    this.context = context;
    this.reviewers = reviewers;

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "CustomReviewerAdapter - getView");
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_reviewer, parent, false);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "CustomReviewerAdapter - getView - convertview was null");

    }
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_detail_reviewerlist_author);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_detail_reviewerlist_content);
    textView1.setText(reviewers[position].getAuthor());
    textView2.setText(reviewers[position].getContent());
    Log.v(LOG_TAG1, "CustomReviewerAdapter - getView - data set");
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Fragment Detail Reviewer:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id ="@+id/imageView_layout"
android:orientation = "vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_reviewerlist_author"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_reviewerlist_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
```

Fragment Detail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_list"
    android:editable="false" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_reviewerlist"
    android:editable="false" />
```

Below is activity from which fragment is being initiated. The first fragment is working fine and is being displayed. However the second fragment is where I dont get anything displayed. Is below correct way to initiate two fragments?

Detail Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    intentData = extras.getStringArray("moviedetails");
    MovieDetailFragment movieDetailFragment = new MovieDetailFragment();
    movieDetailFragment.setMovieDetails(intentData);
    MovieReviewerFragment movieReviewerFragment = new MovieReviewerFragment();
    movieReviewerFragment.setMovieDetails(intentData);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container_1, movieDetailFragment)
                .add(R.id.container_2, movieReviewerFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call the LayoutInflater like this:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Thanks Mariano. I have fixed my code with above and still issue is not resolved. I am not sure what else I am messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the lines

```
movieDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.setAdapter(movieDetailAdapter);
```

To

```
listView.setAdapter(movieDetailAdapter);
movieDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

First you set the adapter, then you send the notification. If you do this the reverse way, there is no `ListView` which may display the updated data.

You can automate these notifications with

```
movieDetailAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have made the change and still have the same issue. There is still something wrong in my code.

Comment: Will check this issue more detailed today and update if I find the other issue.

Comment: Is your onPostExecute method getting called?